# Using timewarp with autoresponder in MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp

I'm looking for a way to use MailChimp's timewarp feature with autoresponder. It doesn't look possible via the autoresponder control panel, but I was wondering if this is possible via the MailChimp API? Has anyone tried anything similar?

S

Comment: Wouldn't that be bad, if someone purchased right now and gets the confirmation at 9am?!? ;)

Comment: I'm offering a free course which is distributed over 4 days. My current subscribers are in the UK, USA and Australia. It's important that they receive each email first thing in the morning.

Comment: Have you tried if it is automatically implemented?

Comment: I've set up the 4 auto responders and everything seems to be working perfectly. The problem is, I can only select one timezone (currently UK, 7am). This is a problem for those in the USA and Australia. Combining timewarp with autoresponder will mean each timezone will receive their email at 7am. This is an important factor for the type of course I'm providing.

Comment: Have you tried to send the mails out to people and see, if timewarp is immediately accessed to? Did get that point not. ;)

Comment: Timewarp is not available when you set up an autoresponder. You can select just 1 timezone.

Comment: Timewarp is set in [relation](https://us1.admin.mailchimp.com/account/defaults/) to `When you schedule campaigns, we'll use this timezone as a reference`. However, I went through it and autoresponders are, as in my first comment, to trigger on `certain` activities. What you plan sounds more like a campaign!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the response from MailChimp below. Hope this helps anyone else who is looking to do the same.

> Thanks for emailing into support. That's a great question and I'll be
>   happy to provide a bit more information.
>
> Currently Timewarp is only available for use on campaigns,
>   specifically Regular, Plain-text, and A/B Split campaigns. It would
>   not be possible to set up an autoresponder using the Timewarp feature
>   at the moment. Autoresponders are technically complex, and adding
>   Timewarp into the mix increases that complexity. Even with the API,
>   it's currently not possible to set the Timewarp flag to true for an
>   autoresponder using the campaign create function.